# RPM installation %post macro works on terminal but not on GUI

Tags: centos, gnome, rpm, rpmbuild

I have created my own .rpm file. The installation works prefect on the command line but doesn't work properly when i am doing it from the GUI.

The only thing that doesn't work from the GUI is the %post script.
I try to invoke the browser post installation, works when i run through the command line but not through GUI.

Here is the .spec file used for rpm building

```
Name:sample_rpm
Version:1.0
Release:1%{?dist}
Summary:Sample RPM package for testing post install script

Group:Development/Tools
License:GPL
URL:None
Source0:sample_rpm.tar.gz

%description
Sample rpm for testing post install script

%prep
%setup -n sample_rpm

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/sample_rpm"
cp -R * "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/sample_rpm"

%post
exec "/usr/bin/firefox" "http://www.google.com" &

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
/opt/sample_rpm/
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First define a macro e.g:

```
%define runcommand() ( /usr/bin/firefox http://google.com )
```

Then under the `%post` section run `%runcommand`.  Since the package requires root access and `root` the `%post` macro won't be able to find a DISPLAY. Exporting DISPLAY environment variable should solve this problem. For example

```
......
%post
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
%runcommand
.........
```

Finally, use  `rpmlint -i sample_rpm.spec`  to check if there are errors. If no errors there, build the package using `rpmbuild -ba sample_rpm.spec`

Comment: No luck! this is the error i get - > No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
warning: %post(sample_rpm-1.0-1.el6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Comment: @AvinashNair  Ok, so what does `echo "$DISPLAY"` tell you prior building the rpm?  Try then  `su -c 'rpm -ivh sample_rpm'` and tell me what you get.

Comment: Prior to building the rpm $DISPLAY is empty

Comment: @AvinashNair  use the snippet in my answer and see if this changes anything.